# ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I followed the "Spring Boot Tutorial for Beginners #1" at https://youtu.be/jj2rNQuLEbg and ended up running the entire microservice perfectly, using the original `Maven`-based configuration (`pom.xml`). All built and run on `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1`, not Eclipse as in the tutorial.

However, when I tried to port this same exact source code to a `Gradle-based configuration (`build.gradle`), it built perfectly, but at runtime it throws the following exception:

```
6:27:20 PM: Executing ':SpringbootBackendApplication.main()'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :SpringbootBackendApplication.main()

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2023-06-07T18:27:22.961+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : Starting SpringbootBackendApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 17892 (C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\springboot-backend-gradle\build\classes\java\main started by Me in C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\springboot-backend-gradle)
2023-06-07T18:27:22.967+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-07T18:27:23.065+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-07T18:27:23.066+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-07T18:27:24.337+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-07T18:27:24.469+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 118 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-07T18:27:25.653+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-07T18:27:25.671+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-07T18:27:25.671+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-07T18:27:25.789+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-07T18:27:25.792+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2722 ms
2023-06-07T18:27:26.087+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-07T18:27:26.194+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-06-07T18:27:26.710+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-07T18:27:26.989+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3bbe6d14
2023-06-07T18:27:26.992+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-06-07T18:27:27.008+03:00  WARN 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at net.javaguides.springboot.SpringbootBackendApplication.main(SpringbootBackendApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 45 common frames omitted

2023-06-07T18:27:27.030+03:00 ERROR 17892 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-06-07T18:27:27.032+03:00  WARN 17892 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2023-06-07T18:27:27.037+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-07T18:27:27.052+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-06-07T18:27:27.057+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-07T18:27:27.088+03:00  INFO 17892 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-07T18:27:27.156+03:00 ERROR 17892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at net.javaguides.springboot.SpringbootBackendApplication.main(SpringbootBackendApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 45 common frames omitted


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
6:27:27 PM: Execution finished ':SpringbootBackendApplication.main()'.
```

This is my current `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.me'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.15.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:3.0.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:3.0.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What do I need to put in my `build.gradle` to make the same exact source code work without modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the reason for why the **same exact source code** would produce exceptions at runtime when moving from Maven to Gradle (after ironing out tons of build errors via trial-and-error of various Gradle dependencies and plugins), lies in the fact that my `Gradle` build was running `Spring Boot v3.0.6`, while the `Maven` build (downloaded from https://github.com/RameshMF/spring-boot-tutorial-course is running `Spring Boot v2.5.0`.

```
C:\Users\Me\.jdks\corretto-17.0.7\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52748:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\springboot-backend-maven\target\classes; ...

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)

2023-06-08 16:07:29.273  INFO 6324 --- [           main] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : Starting SpringbootBackendApplication using Java 17.0.7 on unity with PID 6324 (C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\springboot-backend-maven\target\classes started by Me in C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\gs-spring-boot\springboot-backend-maven)
2023-06-08 16:07:29.279  INFO 6324 --- [           main] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-06-08 16:07:30.564  INFO 6324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-08 16:07:30.662  INFO 6324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 85 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-08 16:07:31.869  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-08 16:07:31.896  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-08 16:07:31.897  INFO 6324 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2023-06-08 16:07:32.069  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-08 16:07:32.069  INFO 6324 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2683 ms
2023-06-08 16:07:32.436  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-08 16:07:32.545  INFO 6324 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.31.Final
2023-06-08 16:07:32.785  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-06-08 16:07:32.940  INFO 6324 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-08 16:07:33.157  INFO 6324 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-06-08 16:07:33.179  INFO 6324 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2023-06-08 16:07:34.106  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-06-08 16:07:34.117  INFO 6324 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-08 16:07:34.609  WARN 6324 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-06-08 16:07:35.199  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-08 16:07:35.214  INFO 6324 --- [           main] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : Started SpringbootBackendApplication in 6.799 seconds (JVM running for 7.553)
2023-06-08 16:07:35.216  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-06-08 16:07:35.218  INFO 6324 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
```

All the issues that I encountered in the process of attempting to make the `Gradle` build work, were simply derivatives, symptoms and "red herrings"...

Why I did not *immediately* notice the `v3.0.6` vs. `v2.5.0` difference is beyond me.

The way I eventually reached that point is by going back to the Maven based project and, using the Maven tool, captured the versions of the various dependencies:

[image: IntelliJ Maven tool]

I then used that to re-write my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
}

group = 'com.me'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.0'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.5.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3'
    implementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.19.0'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.9.0'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.9.0'
    implementation 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.7'
    implementation 'org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.8.2'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The Gradle-based service is running now perfectly...

Of course, any newly developed `Spring Boot` code should run the latest and greatest, but for the purpose of understanding the delicate inter-dependencies between the various pieces of this tricky environment (DI, Lombok, versions, etc.) this was a great exercise.

Answer (score 5):

Have you upgraded the hibernate dependency during the maven -> gradle migration?

The `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` class was removed from hibernate-core with the 6.x release.
Either use the exact same versions as in the pom.xml or you can simply use the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` class instead.

Comment: Yes, I did. I let IntelliJ do the "magic" of converting the project from Maven to Gradle and I am not sure that I understood what it was doing. After posting my question, I actually tried to do exactly was you suggested ("use the exact same versions as in the pom.xml") but now I am getting: *"java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider"* when run (despite successful build). Can you elaborate on how to use `MySQLDialect` instead?

Comment: In your properties file (src/main/resources) you have to change either the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` or `spring.jpa.database-platform` property, whichever you are using to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`. For this to work keep the updated versions.